# Can we show different types of map views?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

I have to show different types of map views as in the google map there are 2 views.
So I want to know how can we show different map views using `mapkit`in iphone application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mapType**
The type of data displayed by the map view.

```
@property(nonatomic) MKMapType mapType
```

Discussion:

Changing the value in this property may cause the receiver to begin loading new map content. For example, changing from **MKMapTypeStandard** to **MKMapTypeSatellite** might cause it to begin loading the satellite imagery needed for the map. If new data is needed, however, it is loaded asynchronously and appropriate messages are sent to the receiver’s delegate indicating the status of the operation.